# "Array item" and constant "define" shows only 0 and not the whole number

Tags: php, arrays

I declared an array item "0859" but when I display the array item, it shows only the 0 and not the whole number "0859".

In constant define I set the value to "01238" the result is the same with my array, it shows only the value 0 and not the whole number 01238. I would like to know further about the reason why array item and define that starts with 0 in there item and values shows only the 0 and not the whole number

Array

```
<?php
  $num = [0859];
  echo $num;

  output: 0

  Why not the the output is "0859"
?>
```

Constant Define

```
<?php

  define(myNum, 01238);
  echo myNum;

  output: 0

  Why not the the output is "01238"
```

?>

I'm using Wamp PHP version 5.5.12

Please enlighten me why I get the output only 0 and not the whole number

Comment: Why not put it as a string already ? Like this $num = ["0859"];

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: Check this link http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse error: Invalid numeric literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40735963/parse-error-invalid-numeric-literal)

Comment: @GeekSilva no I don't want to put the number as a string.

Comment: @BrianMoreno I dont know what exactly type of PHP version I'm using right now. I will check it later. Is there a problem with my PHP version that I'm using right now that cause a problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running PHP7 you should probably take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40736053/3422027) answer.

As said in the linked answer:

> This comes from the changes made to how integers, specifically octals,
>   are handled in PHP7 (as oppsoed to PHP5).
>
> Invalid octal literals
>
> Previously, octal literals that contained invalid numbers were
>   silently truncated (0128 was taken as 012). Now, an invalid octal
>   literal will cause a parse error.
>
> Either use them as strings, or actual integers
>
> $a = array(1, 8, 9, 12); // Integers
>
> $a = array("00001", "00008",
>   "00009", "00012"); // Strings

You can find more info on Integers/Octals here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: I'm not sure If I'm using PHP 5.6 or PHP 7 version right now. I'll check my PHP later, Right now the problem is that it only display "0"

Answer (score 0):

With full credit to [Qirel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4535200/qirel) and his answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40736053/2288334

This is likely due to how PHP is handling what used to be silently parsed to octal literals now is not. Basically, PHP7 thinks you're trying to pass an octal as the only value of the array, but it is invalid.

For Reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.integers.invalid-octals
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: If it is a duplicate on SO, do not repost a solution.  Please remove your answer and flag to close as duplicate.