# Pdo select statement doesnt display data from database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<?php
$localhost ="localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "sbnhs";
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$localhost;dbname:$dbname", $username, $password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    // echo "Success";
    $x = 0128;
    $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $dbname.refcitymun WHERE provCode = :provcode");
    $sql->bindValue(':provcode', $x);
    if($sql->execute()) {
        while($result = $sql->fetch()){
            $desc = $result['citymunDesc']; 
            echo $desc;
        }   
    }else {
        echo 'Query Error';
    }
}catch (PDOException $e) {
    print 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '</br>';
    die();
}   

?>
```

I want to display the data in my address column but it does not display anything nor error. I dont know what is wrong with the code

```
<?php
$localhost ="localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "sbnhs";
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$localhost;dbname:$dbname", $username, $password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    // echo "Success";
    // $x = 0128;
    $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $dbname.refcitymun WHERE provCode = 0128");
    // $sql->bindValue(':provcode', $x);
    if($sql->execute()) {
        while($result = $sql->fetch()){
            $desc = $result['citymunDesc']; 
            echo $desc;
        }   
    }else {
        echo 'Query Error';
    }
}catch (PDOException $e) {
    print 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '</br>';
    die();
}   

?>
```

But when i try the format above it display the data that i want. But i need to use variable  in the statement. Please check what is wrong with the first code

Comment: `0128` is octal notation which is a different number in decimal.

Comment: `$x = 0128;` should error out, as it isn't even a valid octal number (although older versions will just silently truncate it to `012`, see (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40736053/2422776 for details)

Comment: @u_mulder any suggestion on how to solve this problem? Do i need to convert octal to decimal?

Comment: @Mureinik ahhh, im not aware of it but i tride to put `quotation` and it display the data. Thank you for the information

Comment: Change `$x = 0128;` to `$x = 128;`.

Comment: @Barmar but if i tried that there will be no result because the column in database start with 0 so i just change the datatype of my variable to string

Comment: What is the datatype in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Provide third parameter (appropriate data type) in `bindValue`:

Change following line:

```
$sql->bindValue(':provcode', $x);
```

To

```
$sql->bindValue(':provcode', $x, PDO::PARAM_STR);// This will work if your provcode is of type int, provide appropriate datatype
```

Comment: I already tried the second one but still it does not display any data

Comment: Is `PDO::PARAM_STR` it working?

Comment: I change the type of variable to string and it solve everything that i want. Im so stupid. Btw Thanks closed already

Comment: That's why i mentioned a comment "This will work if your provcode is of type int, provide appropriate datatype"

Comment: since im not aware on octal notation. Thank you for help