# Phone number and Invalid numeric literal

Tags: php

I have seen this :
[Parse error: Invalid numeric literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40735963/parse-error-invalid-numeric-literal)
But octal numbers is not my problem
I using phone numbers as arguments in a function call; for example while running this code error occurred

```
<?php
var_dump(0917078452);
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: phone numbers and postal codes can start with "0". if you don't use it as a string php parses the integer without the 0 at at the start. `$int = 012344; echo $int;` this should show you 1234 and not 01234 as aspected

Comment: You have to write phone numbers and postcodes as strings. var_dump('0917078452');