# PHP: mktime() parse error invalid numeric literal

Tags: php

I need to set variable, let's call it `$times` to specific amount of 8AM. I tried using `mktime(08,00)` but it returns

> Parse error: Invalid numeric literal

Since I'm new to php, I still don't know which function is best used for thing such as this, weather it is time() date() or so.

**My question is:** how do I set `$times` to be 8AM of current day?

### **I've checked a lot of similar questions, but none of them have an answer. Not even the one that this is marked duplicate of.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse error: Invalid numeric literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40735963/parse-error-invalid-numeric-literal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the leading zeros.

```
mktime(8, 0);
```

It's because PHP is interpreting `08` as an octal number, and 8 is out of range in octal (0-7).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Dateformat reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

```
$time = date("H:i") // 08:00
```